# Error while trying to create simple thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Im trying to create a simple thread and have it execute.

My function definition is:

```
void MyClass::myFunction()
{
   //Do Work
}
```

I'm creating the thread and executing it:

```
std::thread t1(myFunction);
```

Upon compiling my code, i get the following error:

```
error C3867: function call missing argument list; use '&MyClass::myfunction' to create a pointer to member.
```

Since my function does not take any parameters, i'm assuming i'm declaring it wrongly where i'm creating my thread? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!!

Comment: The compiler is pretty explicit about what to do here

Comment: Yes i've tried creating the pointer to member by prepending the & in front of the function name such as:

std::thread t1(&myFunction);

But then i get: error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

Comment: Is the member function `static`? If not then you need to pass an instance of `MyClass` as the first argument to the thread.

Comment: You'll also need to pass a pointer to an instance of `MyClass`. Alternatively make your function `static`.

Comment: I feel really stupid, the compiler pretty much gave me all i needed to fix the error. I've used:
std::thread t1(&MyClass::myFunc); and it's worked, Thanks all!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If your method is a **non-static** member : You need an instance of your object to call the member function on.
- If your method is **static** member, do what the compiler suggest : simply pass the address of your function.

**Example**:

```
class A
{
    public:
        void foo() { cout << "foo"; }

        static void bar() { cout << "bar"; } 
};

int main() {
    std::thread t1(&A::foo, A()); // non static member
    t1.join();

    std::thread t2(&A::bar);   // static member (the synthax suggested by the compiler)
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```